# videojs: Video streaming loading when url throws 404

Tags: javascript, angular, video-streaming, html5-video, video.js

I am using video.js library to stream live video and it is working as expected

but after some time url throws a 404 error while streaming and the whole player will stuck on loading, now i want to catch that 404 error in any event and handle that

i also tried with `player.on("error")` but it is not firing when chunk is throwing 404

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed new library **videojs-errors**

```
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'videojs-errors';
```

which solved my problem with reach message options and customization

Answer (score 1):

You can try listening to these events: `playliststuck` / `retryplaylist`. You can pass a callback function to `.on` method of the tech object.

Example:

```
const playerTech = player.tech({ IWillNotUseThisInPlugins: true });

playerTech.on('retryplaylist', (e) => { } );

playerTech.on('usage', (e) => { });
```

Comment: Thanks Dario Fiore for your help but actually i found new library called videojs-errors which is supporting extra errors than videojs library and i am able to catch it